# How to remove breakpoint visual studio express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I am working on a C# project in Visual Studio 2010 express, I have a breakpoint that only shows up when I am in the debug modus, I can remove it there, but it will show up again as soon as I start the debug modus again. Allways on a specific codeline, I tried to leave that line empty, then it jumped to the next one. It didnt showed up as I comented the whole code after that line out.

I dont have a breakpoint window in the debug menu ( maybe because it is the express version) so I can't acces to the "remove all breakpoints" function. Do I have to do some change in one of the debug files? Wich one?

thanks

Comment: And it's gone, just like that... I was clicking trough the project files in the explorer, and then the breakpoint showed up outside of the debug modus, so i just removed it, and it didn't showed up again...

Comment: I was fighting this breakpoint for 3 days, and now it has gone and I don't have any idea of what hapened. Can someone explain this?